# Django custom User Model : I can't assign a user to a group in admin panel

Tags: python, django, web

I have created a custom User Model in my app. But, now, in the administration panel, I can't assign a user to a group or a permission because the right table doesn't appear.

How do I solve this problem?

**SCREENS TO UNDERSTAND :**

without custom user model :
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBLda.png)

now, with the custom user model, the right table is not :
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO4uC.png)

**CODE :**

admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email')
    search_fields = ('username',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ['wide'],
            'fields': ('username', 'password')
        }),
        ('Informations personnelles', {
            'classes': ['wide'],
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'avatar')
        }),
        ('Permissions', {
            'classes': ['wide'],
            'fields': ('is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups', 'permissions')
        }),
        ('Dates importantes', {
            'classes': ['wide'],
            'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')
        }),
    )
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    signup_token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, unique=True, verbose_name="jeton d'inscription", null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = CloudinaryField('image', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Do you have ```admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)``` in your admin.py ?

Comment: I had `admin.site.register(User)`, so I add `UserAdmin` and now I have this error : « Unknown field(s) (permissions) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdmin.»
If I delete 'permissions' field in my fieldset (admin.py), i don't have the error but it still doesn't work, I have the same problem.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. Here on Stack Overflow, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! You are encouraged to [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, by dint of digging through the docs, I finally found it. For those interested, add this line to admin.py:

```
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

Doc source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal